# How to sum specific rows of pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data:

```
    W   X   Y   Z   Pnl
A   1   0   0   0   25    
B   1   1   0   0   34    
C   1   0   0   0   -15    
D   0   0   0   1   2    
E   0   1   0   0   88    
F   1   0   0   0   -46
```

I would like the following output:

```
W   -2  # =25+34-15-46
X   122    
Y   0    
Z   2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: ok sure...thank you

Comment: `df.iloc[:,:-1].mul(df['Pnl'].values, axis=0).sum(axis=0)`

Comment: @Andreas Its minimal reproducible example now :P

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, so possible multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) all columns (`Pnl` is removed by `pop`), last sum per rows by [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df = df.mul(df.pop('Pnl'), axis=0).sum() 
print (df)
W     -2
X    122
Y      0
Z      2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Solve this by performing broadcasted multiplication on the first 4 columns, then sum the rows:

```
df.iloc[:,:-1].mul(df['Pnl'], axis=0).sum()

W     -2
X    122
Y      0
Z      2
dtype: int64
```

Where,

```
df.iloc[:,:-1].mul(df['Pnl'], axis=0)

    W   X  Y  Z
A  25   0  0  0
B  34  34  0  0
C -15   0  0  0
D   0   0  0  2
E   0  88  0  0
F -46   0  0  0
```

You can also use `df.mul(df.pop('Pnl'), axis=0).sum()` but beware that **`pop` destructively modifies `df`** , avoid if you need to preserve the input.

---

If performance is important, use `numpy`:

```
# <0.24 versions 
(df.pop('Pnl').values[:,None] * df.values).sum(axis=0)
# v0.24 onwards
(df.pop('Pnl').to_numpy()[:,None] * df.to_numpy()).sum(axis=0)
# array([ -2, 122,   0,   2])

pd.Series((df.pop('Pnl').to_numpy()[:,None] * df.to_numpy()).sum(axis=0),
          index=df.columns)

W     -2
X    122
Y      0
Z      2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What you described in a now-deleted comment to jezrael's answer is called a tag wiki on Stack Overflow. You don't need to create a locked Q&A to contain a list of canonical questions. Those go in the tag wiki. See the tag wikis for [tag:x86] and [tag:c++] for some good examples.

Comment: Thanks, @Cody. Didn't know that was a thing but it is definitely a more appropriate place. The only issue with tag wikis is that it doesn't attract many eyeballs and is less SEO friendly than a post. Either way, it's a start.

Comment: Yeah, tag wikis don't have the visibility that they need. It's a perennial feature request on Meta; long ignored. It is quite surprising to me that you hadn't heard of them. That an active and engaged user has completely missed them speaks to an even greater problem than I had realized.

Comment: @Cody I should probably clarify: I am aware of the existence of tag wikis (heck, [I've even contributed to one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info)). What I meant was I didn't know reference QAs like the PHP and regex ones I've seen were actually more popularly maintained as part of tag wikis (like in the c++ examples you linked to). The point stands however that there is a glaring issue with the tag wiki - no one reads them.

Answer (score 0):

```
pnl = df[['Pnl']]
df.drop(['Pnl'],axis=1,inplace=True)
res = pd.DataFrame(df.values * pnl.values,columns=df.columns)
final_res= res.sum(axis=0)
```

output:

```
W     -2
X    122
Y      0
Z      2
```